# problem with zlib1g-dev and libncurses5-dev

Tags: apt, 18.04

I am really new to the Ubuntu world, and I am facing this problem with  zlib1g-dev.

This is the version of my system:

```
lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS
Release:    18.04
Codename:   bionic
```

I am trying to install samtools, following the main page https://github.com/samtools/samtools/blob/develop/INSTALL. Unfortunately, when I try to install the prerequisites as this

```
udo apt-get update  # Ensure the package list is up to date
sudo apt-get install autoconf automake make gcc perl zlib1g-dev libbz2-dev liblzma-dev libcurl4-gnutls-dev libssl-dev libncurses5-dev
```

and I get this output

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
autoconf is already the newest version (2.69-11).
autoconf set to manually installed.
automake is already the newest version (1:1.15.1-3ubuntu2).
automake set to manually installed.
make is already the newest version (4.1-9.1ubuntu1).
make set to manually installed.
gcc is already the newest version (4:7.4.0-1ubuntu2.3).
gcc set to manually installed.
libbz2-dev is already the newest version (1.0.6-8.1ubuntu0.2).
perl is already the newest version (5.26.1-6ubuntu0.5).
perl set to manually installed.
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libncurses5-dev : Depends: libtinfo-dev (= 6.1-1ubuntu1.18.04) but it is not going to be installed
 python3.9 : Depends: libpython3.9-stdlib (= 3.9.13-1+bionic1) but 3.9.10-1+bionic1 is to be installed
 python3.9-minimal : Depends: libpython3.9-minimal (= 3.9.13-1+bionic1) but 3.9.10-1+bionic1 is to be installed
 zlib1g-dev : Depends: zlib1g (= 1:1.2.11.dfsg-0ubuntu2.2) but 1:1.2.11.dfsg-0ubuntu2.1 is to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

could you suggest me a way to proceed? I tried apt --fix-broken install, but I got more errors..
Thank you in advance.

Update

```
sudo apt policy libtinfo-dev

libtinfo-dev:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 6.1-1ubuntu1.18.04
  Version table:
     6.1-1ubuntu1.18.04 500
        500 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 Packages
     6.1-1ubuntu1 500
        500 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages

sudo apt policy libpython3.9-stdlib
libpython3.9-stdlib:
  Installed: 3.9.10-1+bionic1
  Candidate: 3.9.13-1+bionic1
  Version table:
     3.9.13-1+bionic1 500
        500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/deadsnakes/ppa/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages
 *** 3.9.10-1+bionic1 100
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

Comment: Please add output of `apt policy libtinfo-dev` to the question.

Comment: And also `apt policy libpython3.9-stdlib`. Something is wrong with your sources.list.

Comment: Please add information TO THE QUESTION, not to comments.

Comment: You have some `deadsnakes` PPA that breaks things. It is unclear why `libtinfo-dev`  refuses to install. You can try to install it manually. Regarding other dependencies, you'll have to resolve them manually. Using a PPA can lead to this kind of problems.

Comment: Ok thank you. As I said, I am very new to this world, so I will try to solve the problem

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I resolve unmet dependencies after adding a PPA?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/140246/how-do-i-resolve-unmet-dependencies-after-adding-a-ppa)